# How can I contact the Canadian immigration services regarding my visa application?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

I applied for Canada visa or my parents.

My father got visa and got update in a week in cic portal.

Application for my mother was not updated from July 25th. Last update was, application submitted. Status shows Sumbitted.

> Your application is in progress. We will send you a message once the
>   final decision has been made.

How can I contact cic, to know, they need any extra doc? or how much time it will take to process?

Answer (score 1):

You can check standard processing times for applications here: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/index.asp

For visitor visa, it takes about a month usually.

For parental residency applications, they're working on applications submitted in January 2014 at this time. Assuming this is an application for them to move to canada, you can expect a wait of 4-ish years until they even get to your application. Then about 8 to 12 months to process the application.

The information you see online is as up to date as the information will be by speaking to a person at CIC.

If you still need to contact CIC, you can do so at 1-888-242-2100 in Canada only.
They can't speed up applications or make any decisions.

Comment: This here. It's understandable they do not provide a phone number for the hundreds of thousands of outstanding cases. And yes, it's maddening. Mine only took two years due to an AEO but that was long ago. It was still maddening.